# reading xml file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

I have an xml file with the following structure:

```
< rewriteMaps>  
  < rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites" />  
  < add key="/superstar2011" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4014" />  
  < add key="/superstar2012" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4012" />  
  < add key="/superstar2012" value="/article.aspx?articleid=4012" />  
< /rewriteMaps>
```

I have a gridview with which I want to bind the key and values. How should I go about it?
I am new to xml with gridview. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement x = XElement.Parse("<rewriteMaps><rewriteMap name=\"StaticRewrites\" /><add key=\"/superstar2011\" value=\"/article.aspx?articleid=4014\" /><add key=\"/superstar2012\" value=\"/article.aspx?articleid=4012\" /><add key=\"/superstar2012\" value=\"/article.aspx?articleid=4012\" /></rewriteMaps>");

var r = from i in x.Descendants("add")
                    select new { key = "key", value = "value" };

yourGrid.Datasource = r;
yourGrid.DataBind();
```

or like this example:

```
DataSet dataSet= new DataSet();
string filePath = Server.MapPath("your.xml");

dataSet.ReadXml(filePath);                    
yourGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
yourGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a XMLDatasource.

```
<asp:xmldatasource id="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" datafile="books.xml" />
```

and then Bind it to control as

```
<asp:TreeView id="TreeView1" runat="server" datasourceid="XmlDataSource1">
        <databindings>
          <asp:treenodebinding datamember="book" textfield="title"/>
        </databindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the xml file and collect the data in a datatable or dataset. Then bind the gridview with this datatable or dataset. Once the data is collected in a dataset or datatable, you can simply bind the gridview with the datatable or dataset via the following 2 lines:

```
GridView1.DataSource=ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```